# C# webservice call sometime will never timeout

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have an application written using .net CF 3.5 for windows mobile and windows ce applications. It uses a SOAP webservice to download data from and upload data to our server. We use an auto-generated web reference to call the service.

Normally a call to the webservice will timeout if it can't get a responce from the server, but sometimes the call to the webservice will never time out and will hang indefinitely. I can cause this to happen reasonably often by simulating 50% packet loss.

To get around this issue I have been creating a separate thread to run the call on, and aborting the thread after 4 minutes. I cannot call abort() on the web reference object as this will also hang indefinitely. This solves the immediate problem, however, each time I do this it leaks memory and if I check the threads in the process it will have two more threads each time. Eventually the application will use up all the system memory and will crash.

From what I can tell the HttpWebRequest used by the web reference uses its own thread pool which it runs the request on and each time one of these request hangs it creates another two threads to run the new request on.

I have tested this on a number of Motorola and Intermec devices running different version of Windows Mobile and Windows CE and have the same issue on all of them.

Does anyone know how to prevent the webservice calls from hanging indefinitely?

Comment: do you have a static member in your communication layer, something that might continue working and can't be stopped...

Comment: Are you closing the request and response objects when you are done using them?  It would be even better to surround the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse inside a C# `using` statement.

Comment: We are using an web reference that has been auto-generated by Visual Studio. Visual Studio create a service proxy object that inherits from SoapHttpClientProtocol, so we do not handle the HttpWebRequest in our own code, it is handled by the SoapHttpClientProtocol class. The service proxy object is wrapped in a using statement.

Comment: Just to be sure, you did set the `Timeout` property on the generated class that inherits from `SoapHttpClientProtocol`?